# Conveying "What does it mean?" ("signifie" et "veut dire")

Tags: synonymes

> What does it mean?
>   Qu'est-ce que ça signifie ? et Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?
>
> What does this word mean? 
>   Que signifie ce mot ? et Que veut dire ce mot ?

What is the differences between these (French) turns ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is identical but there is a difference in register.

***Signifier*** is more formal than ***vouloir dire*** so the former would be more common in written material while the latter would be more common in spoken French.

Note that *vouloir dire* is an idiom in your examples but does also exist as a regular sequence where *vouloir* keep its "willingness" meaning :

> *Que **veut dire** Dimitris ?* -> Il **veut dire** qu'il a compris.
>
> *Que **veut dire**/signifie Dimitris ?* -> En grec, Dimitris **veut dire**/signifie "qui appartient à Déméter".

Comment: Oui certainement pour le coté formel dans le langage parlé. Maintenant... étant donné le boulot de l'OP, on peut aussi dire lui dire que *Signifier* s'emploiera plus usuellement en maths et en physique à propos des signes/équations physiques / mathématiques. p=mg : Qu'est ce que cela signifie ? a<4 idem qui évidemment ne manifestent pas la moindre *volonté de dire* quoi que ce soit.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je comprends mais il me semble que *vouloir dire* a deux sens. Le premier où c'est une locution et où il signifie juste *signifier* et le deuxième où c'est une construction générique et où la volonté intervient. *Je n'ai pas compris ce que ça veut dire* = *ce que ça signifie* comparé à *je n'ai pas compris ce qu'il veut dire* = *ce qu'il souhaite exprimer*.

Comment: Oui, oui! Je suis tout à fait d'accord (et j'ai d'ailleurs +1isé) je mentionnais juste un plus usuel dans le contexte pro de l'OP.

Answer (score 2):

For me 'signifie' and 'veut dire' are synonyms. So there is no différence.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y en a aucune en ce qui concerne le sens lorsque l'on demande la signification d'un mot, d'une expression ou d'une unité de langage plus grande, autrement le verbe « signifier » est plus formel.